# In MySQL 5.5: can I capture the output of SHOW ERRORS?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

Is it possible to capture the messages that can be listed with SHOW ERRORS and store them in a log table? Like, is there a table somewhere, that I can select from?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.statements_with_errors_or_warnings 
WHERE last_seen > NOW() - INTERVAL ??? MINUTE;
```

Set a reasonable time limit.

Or query to `performance_schema`, tables `events_statements_current`, `events_statements_history` and `events_statements_history_long`.

Comment: Unfortunately these don't seem to exist in 5.5

Comment: @j4nd3r53n Yes, I have seen my 8.0.17... look for similar system tables in your version.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n Check out [here](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys#overview-of-objects) - it would appear that `sys.statements_with_errors_or_warnings` only appeared in 5.6. To the OP, why are you still using 5.5 - it went end-of-support in Dec 2018?

Comment: @Vérace thanks - as for why I still use 5.5: I'm still new in this job, so I haven't quite got to the point where I can update. There are developers that need to change code (timestamp format has changed), different departments to coordinate etc. The aim is to get to the latest version, but it isn't as simple as all that.

Comment: It never is! :-) Seriously though, I cannot recommend it strongly enough - I mean on 5.5, you don't have Window/Analytic functions, CTEs (the `WITH` clause), `CHECK` constraints... the list goes on. Your productivity should shoot up on upgrade. Having said that, it's worthwhile testing - we do get questions here from time to time of the sort "I've upgraded and now my system is slow...", but in this case, the pros far outweigh the cons and you can always ask here if you have a problem!

Comment: @j4nd3r53n - Why should the devs care what the internal encoding of `TIMESTAMP` is?

Comment: @RickJames They write Java applications, using JPA - each table is represented by a Java class, and the size of TIMESTAMP changed in version 5.6, is my understanding, so the classes have to be modified to accomodate this, which then spreads throughout the applications that use these classes.

Comment: @Vérace We all want all of that, believe me, but I, with my very modest abilities, am the first one in the company who is confident (or stupid) enough to take on the upgrades process. We are talking about tables with more than 2 billion rows. They also want snappy response times for their analytics queries. What could be easier than that ....

Comment: @j4nd3r53n - Billion row tables and snappy analytics?  Do you build and maintain Summary tables?  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Comment: @RickJames I most certainly do. Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't Oracle's MATERIALISED VIEWs, but I emulate them with tables + stored procedures + scheduled events. More work, but not too bad.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n - My tips on MySQL Summary Tables:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables